# MySQL, Insertion and Deletion

Tags: mysql

Relations:

```
Product( maker, model, type )
PC( model, speed, ram, hd, price)
Laptop( model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
Printer( model, color, type, price)

A. Using two INSERT statements, store in the database the fact that PC model 1100 is made by manufacturer C, has a speed of 3.2, and RAM 1024, hard disk 180, and sells $2499
B. Insert the facts that for every pc there is a laptop with the same manufacturer, speed, ram, and hard disk, a 17 inch screen, a model number 1100 greater, and a price 500 more
C. Delete all pc's with less than 100 gigabytes of hd space
D. Delete all laptops made by a manufacturer that doesn't make printers
E. Manufacturer A buys Manufacturer B. Change all products made by b so now they are made by a.
F. For each pc, double the amount of RAM and add 60gb to the amount of hd. 
G. For each laptop made by manufacturer b, add one inch to the screen size and subtract 100 from the price
```

First for each of these examples I am going to modify my database, is there a way to make a quick copy of my database in case I screw up a change?

How might I go about using two insert statements for question A? I know "INSERT INTO R(A,B,C) VALUES (a,b,c);" Should I do INSERT INTO R VALUES xyz AND INSERT INTO R VALUES sqr?

For letter B, is this a constraint? Do I need to remake my database and have it use InnoDB? (I am not sure what that means I just know it means I can use constraints then....?....

Letter C and D are strait forward to me. "DELETE FROM R WHERE ;" ?

For the last three how do I go about making these changes? I am pretty sure the UPDATE command. So something like

```
UPDATE pc SET ram = 2*ram, hd = hd + 60;
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Is this homework? If so it would be a good idea to use the "homework" tag and also to narrow down your questions a bit.

Comment: To back up your database, use `mysqldump -p -u user backupfile.sql . For something more flexible, look into transactions. They allow you to do a series of operations and then either commit them to the database or roll them back if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should always begin with

`start transaction;`

and end with either `commit;` if the changes are as expected or `rollback;` when they are not this will revert the state back to before the start transaction command.

A

```
insert into Product( maker, model, type ) values ('C','1100'...);
insert into PC( model, speed, ram, hd, price) values ('1100',.....);
```

B

```
insert into Laptop( model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price) select model,speed,ram,hd,'17',price-100 from pc;
```

something like this

For the other ones you are on the right track.

Be sure to use the transaction not to mess up your data and you can do as it has been suggested use a mysql dump or simply create back up table with

create table pcBAK as (Select * from pc);

Good luck

Comment: A makes sense but how would I use two INSERT statements?

Comment: I updated the answer with it was missing the insert in product thats why u need 2 of them.

Comment: I cannot get transaction to work. destroyed my database. I did my first query START TRANSACTION. then did a few queries, then did ROLLBACK; This did nothing. It kept every change I made.

Comment: You should refer to the manual for proper use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html

Comment: Here is what happens when I do a transaction. mysql> START TRANSACTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELETE FROM crapTable WHERE model > 2000;
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> ROLLBACK;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Comment: I would look into the mysql logs about the warning you have there might have to do with the auto-commit or the privileges if you are not using root